# webform: additional options for components

Tags: forms, webforms

Im trying to add additional options for webform component but I seem to be unable to read the data out. I successfully managed to save the data into "extra" inside the db. But I'm unable to read it out again.

what I basically did is this:

```
function webform_maxlenght_form_webform_component_edit_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
$form['extra']['message'] = array(
  '#type' => 'textarea',
      '#title' => 'Message',
      '#default_value' => isset($form['extra']['message']) ? $form['extra']['message'] : NULL,
  );
}
```

It saves it perfectly fine into the database under the field "extra" like I wanted but I'm lost as to how to use it later.

Any help is greatly appreciated, if I'm going into a completely wrong direction please say so

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look to the new hook implemented in web form: [hook_webform_select_options_info()](http://api.lullabot.com/hook_webform_select_options_info).

```
function mymodule_webform_select_options_info() {
  $items = array();

  $items['days'] = array(
    'title' => t('Days of the week'),
    'options callback' => 'webform_options_days',
    'file' => 'includes/webform.options.inc',
  );

  return $items;
}
```

The documentation for that hook describes it as follow:

> Define callbacks that can be used as select list options.
>
> ### Return value
>
> An array of callbacks that can be used for select list options. This array should be keyed by the "name" of the pre-defined list. The values should be an array with the following additional keys:
>
> - title: The translated title for this list.
> - options callback: The name of the function that will return the list.
> - options arguments: Any additional arguments to send to the callback.
> - file: Optional. The file containing the options callback, relative to the module root.